# un-recompiled .net application on mono

Tags: .net, mono

I'm new to the whole mono/linux scene, but couldn't find an answer to a simple question:
Given a .net application which only uses mono supported libraries/functions (unintentional):
Will you be able to run it on linux using mono without having to recompile it using the mono compiler ?

My apologies if this is very basic, but with all the info around I'm only ending up more and more confused.

--
Just for information sake:
I'm going to try to use a raspberry pi running debian and mono to run an application called domdomsoft mangadownloader and an application that serves as a httpd server for transfering the files.
Both applications are built in .net and appear very basic, so I'm guessing they are not using any code that would not be supported by mono.

Since I don't have any of the source code, I won't be able to recompile anything.
So I'm hoping that I can just run the .exe's using mono on the raspberry pi.

Comment: Why don't you just do this the other way around? Try it first, ask a *documented* question that describes what you expected, what you got and what you see when it falls over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will be able to, it's the whole point behind mono & .net, as long as you're not using libraries outside of those implemented, it should just work (as in you can literally drag & drop an exe produced for .net & use it on a linux mono box without touching it).

However the application  appearing "basic" doesn't have anything to do with it not using any non-mono functionality. For example if it was made in WPF, even if it's just a simple window with 1 textbox and a button, it just won't run, so you'll need to try & see. If you go to the mono website you also have Tools that take a binary as input & tell you if it will run on mono if that's easier for you.

Comment: "have Tools that take a binary as input & tell you if it will run on mono if that's easier for you". If you refer to MoMA, then it won't be as magical as you state. I do agree with you on "try & see", as that's the only reliable way to test out an app on Mono.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't have any of the source code, I won't be able to recompile anything". This statement alone makes your wish almost impossible to achieve.

Both Mono and .NET are CLR implementations that support MSIL/CIL execution. So if an application is compiled on Windows against .NET to MSIL, Mono has a chance to execute it without problems. But this kind of perfect port has a few strict requirements,

- This application uses a set of API already implemented by Mono, http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility. As the page shows, using MoMA you can check at API level.
- This application itself is designed in a cross platform way (which means it should not assume itself to be running on .NET and Windows). Most applications fail to run on Mono due to their poor design. http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability The page lists all obvious points a good design should pay attention to.
- This application must also adapt to the incompatible spots of Mono and .NET. It happens rarely but can also lead to problems.

You can see from above that even with full source code of an application, porting it to Mono is never an easy task for the developers. So in your case when you have no source code at hand, it is least likely to have the application running on Mono flawlessly.